# Assembly reference hierarchy and constructors

Tags: c#, reference, hierarchy, .net-assembly

I'm hoping that someone can shed a bit of light on the topic of assembly referencing and how the C# compiler determines when it requires a reference to an assembly.

So to set the stage, take the following example:

Assembly 1 (Contains Assembly1Cat and Assembly1Bird):

```
public class Assembly1Bird
{
    public Assembly1Bird()
    {

    }
    public Assembly1Bird(Assembly1Cat cat)
    {
    }

    public Assembly1Bird(Assembly2Dog dog)
    {
    }

}

public class Assembly1Cat
{
}
```

Assembly 2 (Contains Assembly2Dog):

```
public class Assembly2Dog
{
}
```

Then the actual executable:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bird = new Assembly1Bird();
    }
}
```

The assembly reference hierarchy is as follows:
Executable references Assembly1, Assembly1 references Assembly2

This example builds just fine.
However if I change the program main method which instantiates Assembly1Bird to

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cat = new Assembly1Cat();
        var bird = new Assembly1Bird(cat);
    }
}
```

This example will not build as our executable requires a reference to Assembly2...

So my question is: why can we build the solution successfully using the Assembly1Bird parameter-less constructor, but as soon as we try and use Assembly1Bird(cat) constructor (recall that cat is located in Assembly1) we require a reference to Assembly2 (for the Assembly1Bird(dog) constructor).

My best guess here is that as soon as we step away from the default, or the parameter-less constructor and reference any other constructor in the bird class, the compiler examines all constructors, their parameters and their references..

Any solid explanation on this would be most appreciated!

Comment: Because your code directly references other code that requires that type. You cannot expect the compiler to say "It's okay that you're touching a type I have no idea about".. it's a statically typed language.. not a dynamic one. It's down to overload resolution. It goes, "Oh look! A constructor parameter.. lets go find all of the constructors that take a parameter. Here's one, `Cat`. Here's another... wait... `Dog`? What is this?"

Comment: Yep, you are right. That is weird. I demand an explanation!